# What are the causes of a "operation performed with inactive user" error when *creating* a Salesforce object?

Tags: c#, api, insert, salesforce

Using C# and the Salesforce API, I can successfully `update` records, and I can `create` in certain tables.  However, when I attempt to add an Account object, the `create` method reports failure, with the error INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER, message "operation performed with inactive user".  What might this error indicate?

The only user that I see involved is the account I'm using to authenticate, which is certainly active, at least I can log in with it and update records.  It appears to have full rights.

My understanding is that one should not explicitly specify the owner for an object, as Salesforce will set that automatically, so I'm leaving the `Owner` and `OwnerId` fields null in the passed object.  I get the same error if I do explicitly set `OwnerId`, anyway.

I've gone over the docs ([create](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_create.htm), [accounts](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm#topic-title)), but they offer little troubleshooting advice.  Google offers very little on this error message in relation to inserts, though it's clearly an issue for updates.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

I'm using our corporate Enterprise WSDL, API v24.0.  I could share code, but I'm not sure it would help, as it's virtually identical to working `update` code, it's just a different method called in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in the Account setup, you might have automatic account assignment rules which end up assigning the account to a now inactive user.

If its not that, another place to look at are `before insert` and `before update` triggers on Account object. check if there are any and if any of them reassign ownership.

Comment: Per the admin, no we do not use any such rules.  Good idea, though.

Comment: There is a `before insert` trigger, which can change the owner in some circumstances.  It looks like you've spotted it!  I'll leave this question open a little longer while I check for other possibilities, but I'll be back to mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same error in our project.  (It's Ruby-based, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.)

In our case, we were explicitly setting an `OwnerId` in our code which happened to be that of an inactive user.  Changing to a more appropriate value fixed the problem in our case.  (As `OwnerId` is required in our usage, we decided to make an API-specific user which shouldn't become inactive.)